# Retrieve values from a List

Tags: vb.net

I want to store 100 items in a list with properties `PartName` and `PartId`. 
I then want to search on `PartName`, as an example using the word **chair**. From this I then want to retrieve the value of `PartId`.

In the end I will end up with a `PartId` of **125**.

How can I do this?

**Code:**

```
Dim parts As New List(Of Intialization)()

' Add parts to the list.
parts.Add(New Intialization() With {.PartName = "chair",
                                    .PartId = 125})
```

Comment: I don't understand, you have 100 objects and you want to find the one with .PartName = "chair" and then what? Please clarify, and also how are you going to populate the 100 objects?

Comment: `Dim chair = parts.Where(Function(p) p.PartName="chair").FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Want I want to do is create a list where I have the Name and the value. Once I find in the list the name I need to extract the value of the name. The list is already populated.

Comment: Alex gave a good solution. If it's just a key/value pair then you could use a Dictionary instead of a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this in several ways, I´ll show you some LINQ solutions:

```
Dim partToSearch as String = "Chair"
Dim partId as Integer = -1
Dim init = parts.Where(Function(p) p.PartName=partToSearch).FirstOrDefault()
If init IsNot Nothing Then
  partId = init.PartId
End If
```

Or:

```
Dim partToSearch as String = "Chair"
Dim partId = parts.Where(Function(p) p.PartName=partToSearch).Select(Function(v) v.PartId).FirstOrDefault()
```

Or you create a Dictionary like @the_lotus mentioned:

```
Dim partIDsByName as Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
partIDsByName = parts.ToDictionary(Function(k) k.PartName, Function(v) v.PartId)

Dim partToSearch as String = "Chair"
Dim partId = partIDsByName(partToSearch)
```